# How to mock this method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, fastify

I want to mock the below line of code. And please explain how I can mock this in detail as I'm new to javascript and writing test cases. The below code would return a promise.

```
const createPriceConfiguration = (fastify, req) => {
  return fastify.pg.transact(client => insertQuery(fastify, client, req));
};

const client = {
   query: jest.fn(() => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          resolve({ rows: [req.body] });
        });
      })
    };
```

My colleague gave a solution which I'm not able to understand.

```
transact: jest.fn(queryFunction => {
        return queryFunction(client);
      })
```

Comment: Please update your question with more information about what you are trying to do, where this code exists and how it is called, and what exactly you want to mock.  Right now there isn't enough information to help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to test `createPriceConfiguration` function which takes `fastify` object and calls function from it. Mocking this function can be done by mocking the `fastify` object. You need to mock the `transact` method in the `fastify` object passed to return desired response (e.g. promise or result of an other function, ...)

```
const mockedFastify = {
  pg: {
    transact: jest.fn(() => new Promise(resolve => {
      ...desired code
    }))
  }
};
```

Then in test case You pass mocked object `createPriceConfiguration(mockedFastify);`